# Sort SQL request by values of another table

Tags: sql, sorting, pdo

I have a table for products and a table for product reviews. When I display the inventory of products, I'd like the option to sort them by review scoring, but how can I sort one table using values from another table?

**products**

```
product_id | ...
------------------
    1        ...
    2        ...
    3        ...
    4        ...
   ...
```

**reviews**

```
review_id | product_id | user_id | score | ...
------------------------------------------------
   1             2         104       5     ...
   2             1          98       4     ...
   3             2          76       2     ...
   4             3         119       5     ...
  ...           ...        ...      ...
```

I have the list of products in descending order of aggregate review score from below:

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(score)/(COUNT(*)*1.0) AS scoring
    FROM reviews
    GROUP BY product_id
    ORDER BY scoring DESC
```

But I'd like to sort table `products` from this ordering, since alone this is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you do a `JOIN` with `products` table and then sort it like

```
select p.*, tab.scoring
from products p
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT product_id, SUM(score)/(COUNT(*)*1.0) AS scoring
    FROM reviews
    GROUP BY product_id
) tab on p.product_id = tab.product_id
ORDER BY tab.scoring DESC
```